# Probability problem choose 400.000 from 1.000.000

Tags: probability-distributions

When i have 1.000.000 different numbers from 1 to 1.000.000 and 400.000 people choose one of them how can i calculate the probability to choose  for example 300.000 or 200.000 or x DIFFERENT numbers?  In other words how can i calculate the probability of x numbers that not be choosed?

Thanks,
Damian

Comment: So everyone puts his number back into the pot after he drew it?

Comment: I'd use poisson probability that any number independently has zero choices is $\exp(-400000/1000000) = \exp(-.4) = .6703$ so 67.3% of numbers will be unchosen - poisson is justified for this case

Answer (score 0):

I'd use poisson probability that any number independently has zero choices is $exp(−400000/1000000)=exp(−.4)=.6703$

so 67.3% of numbers will be unchosen - poisson is justified for this case - the result was born out by a simulation I ran

if you want to know the probability of a prescise count, such as 670,300, then you would take that binomial probability, .6703, and use the normal sistribution of the binomial distribution to estimate

Answer (score 0):

To follow up Cato, that means the number of empty cells will almost always be within $\sqrt{1000000}=1000$ of 670300.